# Timestamp out of range for platform localtime()/gmtime() function

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I try:

```
ts = -216345600000
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts/1000)
```

**ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform localtime()/gmtime() function**

I check on [epochconverter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) value : -216345600 its return GMT: Sat, 23 Feb 1963 00:00:00 GMT

How to get the correct result?

Comment: what do you want to get... to me your code does not give error

Comment: related: [Get the highest possible gmtime for any architecture](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32045725/4279)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For many values, like too far in the past or the future, just feeding the timestamp to `fromtimestamp()` will complain with an out of range error. However, you can calculate the date using [`timedelta()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) relative from the epoch.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> date = datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=-216345600)
>>> date
datetime.datetime(1963, 2, 23, 0, 0)
>>> date.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
'Sat, 23 Feb 1963 00:00:00 GMT'
```

However, do note that you can't use this to go back to the dinosaur era, since `datetime()` still has a min and max value it can support.

```
>>> datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=-62135596800)
datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=253402300799)
datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59)
>>> datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=253402300800)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#157>", line 1, in <module>
    datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=253402300800)
OverflowError: date value out of range
```

`timedelta()` has its limits as well, but with the epoch as a reference point, we haven't come even near reaching them.

```
>>> timedelta(microseconds=1000000000*86400*10000-1)
datetime.timedelta(9999999, 86399, 999999)
```

Comment: I don't understand why dividing by 1000.

Comment: @D.O. I don't divide anything by 1000. Maybe you're referring to what the OP did? In that case he was converting milliseconds to seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe slightly less related to the problem from the question but may be applicable to those who **want to represent full date-time range without any very specific workarounds** to limitations of the default `datetime` implementation.

I have checked a few libraries and I suggest using:

[`dateparser`](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - for parsing date/time stated naturally for a human being and in multitude of languages.

[`arrow`](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - drop-in replacement for `datetime` without its limitations (e.g. possibility to represent dates before and close to the epoch of 1. year AD).

Comment: Thank you for the arrow module!

Comment: I am in Montreal. I used utcnow() function, it give me 16:20. But now it is 12:20 in Montreal. Why this difference?

Comment: UTC = Universal Time Coordinated or GMT. Montreal's timezone is  (GMT-4) hence the readings. GMT is for London.

Comment: Understand now! Thank you! I use arrow.now() function instead.