# Unable to convert datetime to timestamp before the year 1970

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to convert the datetime object to timestamp so that I can save the time stamp to a json file and later I can convert that timestamp to datetime object.

This worked fine until I set the year greater than 1970, But when decreased the year an exception got raised saying `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

```py
import datetime
cd = datetime.datetime.strptime("1965-12-25", "%Y-%m-%d")
datetime.datetime.timestamp(cd) # this line gives error
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I'm using windows 10 OS. Is there any exception or other way to convert the datetime to timestamp?

Comment: It will give a negative value

Comment: The timestamp 0 (or 1) is on the 1st of January 1970, 00:00:00, then timestamp doesn't really exists before this date

Comment: @Christophe You can use negative offsets from that date to denote prior dates…

Comment: Sunil, you should really use `cd.timestamp()` instead of `datetime.datetime.timestamp(cd)`, but that just as an aside…

Comment: from the [time module's docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html): "*The functions in this module may not handle dates and times before the epoch or far in the future*"

Comment: @deceze I did tried that.. But that gives same exception
And how can I use offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could calculate the negative timestamp as a `timedelta` from the epoch (1970-1-1):

```
import datetime
cd = datetime.datetime.strptime("1965-12-25", "%Y-%m-%d")

ts = (cd-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()

print(ts)
>>> -126835200.0
```

...and the other way round would be something like

```
dt = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=ts)
print(dt)
>>> 1965-12-25 00:00:00
```

---

related:

- [How to convert date before 1970 in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42529995/10197418)
- [In Python, how do you convert a `datetime` object to seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7852855/10197418)