# Frappe throwing ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, frappe

```
for i in data:
        End_Date = i.end_date
        a = int(End_Date)/1000.0

        b = a - 2629743.0
        DateTimeStamp=int(time.time()) 
        if b >= DateTimeStamp:
            mes = "Good to GO" 
        else:
            mes = "Academic year yet to complete"
        Edate = str(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(End_Date)/1000.0).strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
```

Error Line:-  Edate = str(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(End_Date)/1000.0).strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))

ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t

I'm not able to solve this issue.
I tried using

```
Edate = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y',  time.gmtime(int(End_Date)/1000.0))
```

But Still it is showing same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36179914/timestamp-out-of-range-for-platform-localtime-gmtime-function

Comment: I throws the error on """Edate = str(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(End_Date)/1000.0).strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))"""  this line. Why it is not converted to datetime format